# How to post on the wall using stream_publish

Tags: facebook

I got the following exception when i try to post a message on a friends wall using the REST API

> The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

here is my code.

```
$status=$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,null,null,$id,$user);
```

How to get authorization from a user to post a message on his wall? Or any work around to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process, you need to request the `publish_stream` [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) from the user before your application is allowed to post on behalf of that user.

Assuming this is a canvas application, [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas) will probably help you along.